# Is CSRF Token retrieved via API (not embedded in HTML) safe/secure?

Tags: javascript, api, session, csrf, single-page-application

**Most postings on the web say:**

If you've got a pure JavaScript application (single-page app): Just place the CSRF Token in the initial delivered website and you're fine. And reset the token on every important session change, i.e. login/logout.

**But for our new application it's different:**

The server that serves the API cannot interact with the HTML of the single-page app. So it's not possible to place the CSRF Token in the HTML code.

**The questions are:**

- What's the best approach to secure the app against CSRF?
- Is it safe to deliver the CSRF Token via API? (So the JavaScript app will at first call `GET http://.../csrfToken` which **1.** creates a session for the current user (if no session exists) and **2.** associate a new CSRF Token with that session and **3.** deliver that token to the client)
- If delivering via API is safe, should it be placed in the HTTP Header or should I use the response body and use JSON? Or doesn't it matter in terms of safety?
- Should the browser send the token with each (also GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) request?
- Should the browser send the token inside the HTTP Header or within the request body? Or doesn't it matter in terms of safety?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can exchange csrf token even when you are developing an single page app. You must add `"withCredentials:true"` option to your ajax requests and depending on request, you should create the new csrf token in your server. Browser will make the exchange for your CSRF token. At least that's how I do it in my single page app which is developed by using Angular & Django.

Also it's not safe to deliver your CSRF token via API. If CSRF token can be accessed via API, it can be accessed from anywhere, anyone who gets a CSRF token may abuse your system.

Comment: Thanks for your response. ... I think, if delivering via API is not safe, then it must be equally unsafe to deliver it via HTML page, because everyone can access the HTML page. (?!) ... For sure the server generates the token. ... I don't understand what you mean with `"withCredentials:true"`.

Comment: You are right, there's a good discussion about this issue at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-share-csrf-token-to-client-application
withCredentials:true -> see xhrFields part in documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/